# Multiprocessing list manager

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a function that I wish to pass different input files to simultaneously. I am using the multiprocessing manager for the output list, `nodes`. I am defining this as `nodes = manager.list()`

```
file_list = [file_1,file_2,file_3]

def function_x(file,nodes):
    nodes.extend(some_data)     
    print(type(nodes))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    nodes = manager.list()
    matches = partial(function_x,nodes)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    pool.map(function_x,file_list)
```

Despite defining `nodes` as a list, I am getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'`

When I print the `nodes` type I get back `string`. Why is `nodes = manager.list()` not defining this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is in  `matches = partial(function_x, nodes)`.
Here `partial` substitutes the first  `function_x` argument (eg `file`) with `nodes`  and you get filename (a string) in the second argument, hence the error.

So either swap the function_x arguments:

```
def function_x(nodes, filename):
```

or use keyword argument when constructing the partial:

```
matches = partial(function_x, nodes=nodes)
```